# Two questions about vector equations

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, tensor-products, tensors

**Q1. How to write the following equation in a form of $\vec{a}= something$?**

From [the question posted in Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/463232/can-the-following-process-be-justified/463244#463244), I found the following process is wrong.

For any $ \vec{v}\ne\vec{0}$
$$ \vec{v}\cdot\vec{a}+c=0 \quad \Rightarrow  \quad \vec{v}\cdot(\vec{a}+\frac{\vec{v}}{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}}c)=0\quad \Rightarrow  \quad 
\quad \vec{a}+\frac{\vec{v}}{\vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}}c=0\quad \Rightarrow  \quad \vec{a}=-\frac{c}{|\vec{v}|^2}\vec{v}$$

According to RogerJBarlow's answer in the above post, *"this equation tells you the component of $\vec a$ along $\vec v$, but the component of $\vec a$ perpendicular to $\vec v$ is completely arbitrary."*

I want to write the equation in a form of $\vec{a} =something$.

Is it possible? If possible, let me know the method.

**Q2.  Is this true ?**

$$ \vec{v}\cdot\vec{a}+\vec{v}\cdot\vec{c}=0 \quad \Rightarrow  \quad \vec{v}\cdot(\vec{a}+\vec{c})=0\quad \Rightarrow  \quad \vec{a}=-\vec{c}$$

Thank you.

Comment: The problem is that the dot product is not invertible, you are losing information when you take the dot product of $v$ with $a$. Imagine that $v$ and $a$ are orthogonal, then the dot product is $0$ but so is $0\cdot v$ so we don't really know anything specific about $a$ just from its dot product with $v$ except that it's orthogonal to $v$ (in this case). Q2 is not true, the first step is true using linearity of the dot product but the second step is not true, it doesn't imply that $a=-c$ but rather that $a+c$ is orthogonal to $v$.

Comment: @Tony S.F. Thank you. If there is a specific constraint that, in both the questions, the vector quantity in the parenthesis is not orthogonal to $\vec{v}$, can the above steps be justified?

Comment: If $\vec{a} + \vec{c}$ is orthogonal to each vector in a basis of the vector space then you can say $\vec{a} + \vec{c} = \vec{0}$

Comment: @Paul Thank you for your comment. However, why orthogonal? Do you mean "if $\vec a + \vec c$ is not orthogonal to $\vec {v}$"?

Comment: If $\vec{a} + \vec{c}$ is orthogonal to one vector $\vec{v}$ you cannot say much about it, but if it is orthogonal to all vectors in a basis then it must be the zero vector.

Comment: @Paul  I will further think your comment, which may be helpful to me. Thank you very much.